# Data frame transformation in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my data frame.

```
    df<-data.frame(
  Brand=c("Brand_1","Brand_2","Brand_3","Brand_4","Brand_4","Brand_1","Brand_4","Brand_4","Brand_1","Brand_2","Brand_3","Brand_2","Brand_3","Brand_4"),
  M=c("2014-6-1","2014-7-1","2014-8-1","2014-9-1","2014-10-1","2014-11-1","2014-12-1","2015-1-1","2014-2-1","2015-3-1","2014-4-1","2014-5-1","2014-6-1","2014-7-1"),
  Price=c(55,55,55,55,58,58,58,58,58,58,59,60,61,62),
  Quantity=c(140,150,NA,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,100,100,NA,NA,NA,100)
    )

df$M<-as.Date(df$M)


   Brand     M         Price  Quantity
------------------------------------------
1 Brand_1 2014-06-01    55      140
2 Brand_1 2014-11-01    58      200
3 Brand_1 2014-12-01    58      100
4 Brand_2 2014-07-01    55      150
5 Brand_2 2015-03-01    58      100
6 Brand_2 2014-05-01    60       NA
7 Brand_3 2014-08-01    55       NA
8 Brand_3 2014-04-01    59       NA
9 Brand_3 2014-06-01    61       NA
10 Brand_4 2014-09-01    55       NA
11 Brand_4 2014-10-01    58       NA
12 Brand_4 2014-12-01    58       NA
13 Brand_4 2015-01-01    58       NA
14 Brand_4 2014-07-01    62      100
-------------------------------------------
```

I want to change with dplyr or other similar package like table below.Namely after transformation I want to have table like table below, with change of this 4 things:

1. For column M, I want to expand dates between every two variables e.g date should expand between 2014-06-01 and 2014-11-01 like table below (additional 4 variables: 2014-07-01,2014-08-01,2014-09-01,2014-10-01)
2. For column Price, I want to repeat same value for price for every record
3. Column Quantity is same like first table and
4. For column Quantity, first value Quantity 140 should be divide like column Quantity 1,  28=140/5

### Brand     M         Price  Quantity       Quantity1

```
1 Brand_1 2014-06-01    55      140       28
  Brand_1 2014-07-01    55      NA        28
  Brand_1 2014-08-01    55      NA        28
  Brand_1 2014-09-01    55      NA         28
  Brand_1 2014-10-01    55      NA        28
2 Brand_1 2014-11-01    58      200       200
3 Brand_1 2014-12-01    58      100       100
4 Brand_2 2014-07-01    55      150       150
```

---

Upper table is only sample for Brand_1 and Brand_2 and don't include Brand_3 and Brand_4.

Comment: what happened to `Brand_1 2014-02-01    58      100` in this? I mean, why is it not expanded?

Comment: This some error i conversion.Brand_1 2014-02-01 58 100 is actually 2014-12-01 58 100.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for. There might be a but more streamlined way to do it, but this shows the logic.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

First, clean up the `data.frame()` a bit by converting `M` to a date and by sorting on `Brand` and `M`. Then group on `Brand` and use `tidyr::complete()` to fill in the missing months.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(M = as.Date(as.character(M))) %>%
  arrange(Brand, M) %>%
  group_by(Brand) %>%
  complete(M = seq.Date(min(M), max(M), by = '1 month'))
```

Now we have some simple calculations. Create a `Grouping` variable by looking for values without a quantity. The data is already sorted by `M`. Group on this and fill the `Price` down by taking the `min()` of the group, removing NAs. Do something similar for `Quantity1`, but divide by `n()`, the group size.

```
df2 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Grouping = cumsum(if_else(is.na(Quantity),FALSE,TRUE))) %>%
  group_by(Grouping) %>%
  mutate(Price = min(Price, na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(Quantity1 = min(Quantity, na.rm = T) / n())

# Groups:   Grouping [6]
   Brand   M          Price Quantity Grouping Quantity1
   <fct>   <date>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
 1 Brand_1 2014-02-01    58      100        1      25  
 2 Brand_1 2014-03-01    58       NA        1      25  
 3 Brand_1 2014-04-01    58       NA        1      25  
 4 Brand_1 2014-05-01    58       NA        1      25  
 5 Brand_1 2014-06-01    55      140        2      28  
 6 Brand_1 2014-07-01    55       NA        2      28  
 7 Brand_1 2014-08-01    55       NA        2      28  
 8 Brand_1 2014-09-01    55       NA        2      28  
 9 Brand_1 2014-10-01    55       NA        2      28  
10 Brand_1 2014-11-01    58      200        3      66.7
# ... with 23 more rows
```

if you want, you can `ungroup()` at the end and do `select(-Grouping)` to remove this variable.